# Magento 2 - Product images not loading in catalog view

Tags: magento2, product, category, catalog

I noticed that the product images are suddenly not loading in the category view anymore:

[image: images]

in the product view it works just fine.

I inspected the HTML source code and noticed that the images are loaded:

[image]

but why does it not show? I am using the fresh Luma theme without changes.

The server is in production mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After insepecting the browser console I noticed alot of Content Security Policy errors. I solved them, now it works again.

[More infos](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html)